# Python and Google Checkout

Tags: python, authentication, google-checkout

I am trying to use a python script to login and grab the html from my Google Checkout account. It seems to login but returns a strange page:
[image]
Which doesn't have any of the order info which I am trying to parse. I know Google Checkout has an API but there is no way to parse just the payout totals, which is all I care about.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

username = 'username'
password = 'password'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'Email' : username, 'Passwd' : password})
opener.open('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=sierra&passive=1200&continue=https://checkout.google.com/sell/orders&followup=https://checkout.google.com/sell/orders&ltmpl=seller&scc=1&authuser=0', login_data)
resp = opener.open('https://checkout.google.com/sell/payouts')

f = file('test.html', 'w')
f.write(resp.read()) 
f.close()
print "Finished"
```

**How can I get this code to display the proper HTML of my account so I can parse it?**

Comment: Yup, I've raised the need for some *PAYOUT API* (there isn't one) - so perhaps you can help the cause by [suggesting it here](http://support.google.com/checkout/sell/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=suggestions.cs&ctx=cm)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what sort of browser-detection or javascript tricks Google Checkout may be using. It may be enough simply to set your User-Agent to that of a well-known desktop browser- from the screenshot, it seems Google Checkout is assuming you're on a mobile browser.